# Qt: How to adjust QGraphicsItem to dynamicaly change size

Tags: c++, qt

I've this problem for several days. I have created QGraphicsItem and I want to stretch/adjust it's size to size of my QGraphicsView. I was using paint() method, but got with it problems with updating. Now I've used boundingRect() but it uses fixed size. When I set too big size it expand my scene and scrollbars are appearing. Is there way to adjust size of item to size of View?

**EDIT**: I want only adjust height of my object.

Here's some code:

Header of my Item:

```
#ifndef POINTER_H
#define POINTER_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QColor>
#include <QRect>
#include <QGraphicsLineItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

class Pointer : public QGraphicsLineItem
{
public:
    Pointer();
    void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    int position;
    void changePosition(int x);

};

#endif // TRACKPOINTER_H
```

Implementation of my Item:

```
#include "pointer.h"

Pointer::Pointer()
{
    //this->setFlag(QGraphicsLineItem::ItemIsMovable);
    //setFlag(QGraphicsLineItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    //setFocus();

}

void Pointer::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{

    QPen pen(Qt::red);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setBrush(QColor(77,77,77));
    painter->drawLine(0,0,0,2000);

}

QRectF Pointer::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0,0,2,600);
}

void Pointer::changePosition(int x)
{
    //position = x;
    setPos(x,0);
    update();
}
```

And my Window:

```
Window::Window(Timers *timer, TrackPointer *tp)
{
Timeline = new QGraphicsScene(this);
TimelineView = new QGraphicsView(Timeline);
TimelineView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignLeft);

QVBoxLayout *timeLineLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
timeLineLayout->addWidget(TimelineView);

Pointer *pointer = new Pointer;
Timeline->addItem(pointer);
}
```

I have also problems with my scene: When my object moves somewhere away - it expand scene. Later when I bring my object back to it's starting position scene still is expanded and I have scrollbars to scroll my view around the scene. Is there way to decrease scene size using my object?

Comment: You might be interested in [QGraphicsView::resizeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#resizeEvent).

Comment: I've created function resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) in my QgraphicsItem class, but it's not working. I do something wrong I guess.

Comment: You should use the _QGraphicsView_'s resize event and not _QGraphicsItem_'s resize event.

Comment: To do this, I have to create class that inherits from QGraphicsView and got resize Event? And later create object of my custom QGraphicsView class? Is there way to do this without creating custom class? As you can see in my code above I created my QGraphicsView using it's standard class: ''TimelineView = new QGraphicsView(Timeline);''

Comment: Well, inheritance is my prefered way. You may want to use an event filter instead. The point is, that in either case you will be able to catch changes in the view's size and resize the items in your scene accordingly.

Comment: I've created my custom class, but I don't know how to make it resize exactly that one item. I quess it works like that: When I resize my window - it resizes also my custom QGraphicsView. Then during resizing function resizeEvent() start working and.... What's next? How to tell my item to adjust size? Could you please make me example code and post it in this topic?

Comment: maybe you prefer to [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159236/discussion-between-lizard-paszczyk-and-scopchanov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promised example looks something like this:

*MainWindow.h*

```
#include <QMainWindow>

class QGraphicsView;
class QGraphicsRectItem;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override;

private:
    QGraphicsView *m_view;
    QGraphicsRectItem *m_item;
};
```

*MainWindow.cpp*

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    m_view(new QGraphicsView(this)),
    m_item(new QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 1, 1))
{
    m_view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene());
    m_view->setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);
    m_view->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    m_view->setSceneRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
    m_view->installEventFilter(this);
    m_view->scene()->addItem(m_item);

    setCentralWidget(m_view);
    resize(600, 400);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if ((watched == m_view) && (event->type() == QEvent::Resize))
        m_item->setRect(m_view->viewport()->rect().adjusted(5, 5, -5, -5));

    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

look into :QGraphicsView::fitInView

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView

```
QPixmap *pixMap= new QPixmap();;
QGraphicsScene *scene=new QGraphicsScene();;
pixMap->loadFromData(jpegData);
scene->clear();
pixMapItem = scene->addPixmap(*pixMap);
ui->graphicsView->fitInView(scene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
ui->graphicsView->show();
ui->graphicsView->viewport()->update();
```

Comment: fitInView scales item with it's coordinance system, so if I later want to move item by 5px, it goes more than I want